# CAN bus with single node will spam errors until it breaks

Tags: linux, can-bus

Situation:

- we have a pc with a [USB2CAN adapter](https://www.inno-maker.com/product/usb2can-x2-device/)
- we have a single node (us) because the other node is a vehicle cable which may get disconnected
- if we write on the can without another node it will fail (of course) but the issue is that errors (error-pass) will be thrown every second and sooner or later they will **invisibly** break the can bus
- invisibly means if I reboot the pc the can interface will look ok but no messages will pass through
- I've seen I could use the gs_usb driver in python-can but since I can break stuff using simply cansend I don't think it'll make any difference

```bash
$ ip a l can0
4: can0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 10
    link/can

# qlen here is 100000 because I tried upping it from 1 but it did not work
# the state will go back to ERROR-ACTIVE when the cable is connected
# error-warn goes up once when the cable is disconnected
# error-pass goes up around 2k per second, even with a single message sent

$ ip -details -statistic link show dev can15: can1: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 100000
    link/can  promiscuity 0 minmtu 0 maxmtu 0 
    can state ERROR-PASSIVE restart-ms 0 
          bitrate 500000 sample-point 0.875 
          tq 125 prop-seg 6 phase-seg1 7 phase-seg2 2 sjw 1
          gs_usb: tseg1 1..16 tseg2 1..8 sjw 1..4 brp 1..1024 brp-inc 1
          clock 48000000 
          re-started bus-errors arbit-lost error-warn error-pass bus-off
          0          0          0          3          10578541   0         numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped missed  mcast   
    84628424   10578553 0       0       0       0       
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    2          1        0       0       0       0
```

Other infos:

- os is linux Debian (Crunchbang++)
- can is set up with `ip link set can1 type can bitrate 500000`
- there is [an issue](https://github.com/INNO-MAKER/usb2can/issues/5) on the vendor repo which may look like mine (no solution provided)
- we tried with another can to usb adapter from another vendor and it had the same behaviour
- the only solution is removing current to the adapter, I tried removing current from the USB port via software to the adapter but it did not work

```bash
$ lsusb --tree -v
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 5000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        ID 0424:5534 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) Hub
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        ID 0424:2134 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) Hub
        |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            ID 0eef:c000 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd Multitouch Capacitive Touchscreen eGalaxTouch EXC3188-4643-08.00.00.00 Sirius_4643 PCAP3188UR Series [IIyama Prolite PLT1932MSC
        |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
            |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 1, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
                ID 1d50:606f OpenMoko, Inc. Geschwister Schneider CAN adapter
            |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=gs_usb, 12M
                ID 1d50:606f OpenMoko, Inc. Geschwister Schneider CAN adapter
            |__ Port 2: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=gs_usb, 12M
                ID 1d50:606f OpenMoko, Inc. Geschwister Schneider CAN adapter
            |__ Port 2: Dev 10, If 1, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
                ID 1d50:606f OpenMoko, Inc. Geschwister Schneider CAN adapter

$ dmesg
...
[    9.697798] usb 2-1.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d50, idProduct=606f, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    9.697802] usb 2-1.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    9.697805] usb 2-1.3.2: Product: USB2CAN v1
[    9.697807] usb 2-1.3.2: Manufacturer: InnoMaker
[    9.697810] usb 2-1.3.2: SerialNumber: 002C00...
...
[   10.154148] gs_usb 2-1.3.1:1.0: Configuring for 1 interfaces
[   10.154921] gs_usb 2-1.3.2:1.0: Configuring for 1 interfaces
[   10.155372] usbcore: registered new interface driver gs_usb
...
[   12.461996] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): can0: link becomes ready
...
[   15.439110] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): can1: link becomes ready
[   15.572371] can: controller area network core
[   15.572501] NET: Registered protocol family 29
[   15.589581] can: raw protocol
```

python can viewer logs

```bash
Count   Time           dt          ID          DLC  Data (changed)
17      0.002219       0.000000    0x004       8    00 30 00 00 00 00 80 00
208182  122.054997     0.000723    0x024       8    00 30 00 00 00 00 80 00
# my test packet
14      0.000000       0.000000    0x123       2    12 34
```

I have another project where you can remove the can connectors and writing on the bus will throw an error but it won't trigger an error cascade so I'd just like to replicate this behaviour

I don't know if this is a hardware or software issue so I posted here on stackoverflow (there are 74 pages of can-bus threads while others *overflow have few results)

something else I'll test

- loopback mode
- use a virtual can to consume the non acknowledged errors
- set the can adapter as "active" somehow so it also ACKs the messages

Comment: Borderline software/hardware questions are better off at https://electronics.stackexchange.com. However I suspect you'll find a broader audience of users of the various weird Linux "sockets" for CAN at this site. Anyway it sounds as if your node is going "error passive" and then "bus off". For point-to-point CAN communication using an USB-to-CAN adapter, you need to ensure that the adapter is configured to ACK messages on the bus and not just passively listen (often the default option).

Comment: For common hardware problems such as missing terminating resistors, here's a FAQ: [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251)

Comment: @Lundin I talked to an electronic engineer and he also thinks I need to configure the adapter, but I have no idea how to do it (I'm more of a pure programmer). Do you mean connecting to it and sending some parameters, compile and flash a new firmware or make use of ip link/cantools/etc? On the repository there's a lot of code but it's not clear if there's also something useful. As for the errors, I already know that my issue is that I have a single node. When the cable is connected everything works 100% correctly, I just want to either clear the errors or avoid spamming them

Comment: This is a software setting. It should be available through some means provided by the manufacturer of the adapter. Usually called "passive listener", "ack/no ack" or some such. I haven't used this brand so I wouldn't know.